# Tango ADF Inspector has stopped

Tags: google-project-tango

Recently I have updated the Tango Core to the latest version 'zaniah', but now I get a problem after exploring an area.

When I try to load the Area Description File with the 'Project Tango ADF Inspector' it crashes and I get the following error.   "Unfortunately, Project Tango ADF Inspector has stopped".

Comment: I have tried reinstalling both, the Tango service and the ADF inspector itself without any success.  In older vesions it worked fine.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling the new Tango Core App and leaving the (deprecated-legacy) Tango Core without no results. So I suspect that it involves the Tango explorer way of saving an ADF file, that now the ADF Inspector is unable to read.